# Вопросы по работе с модулем Services

Tags: xml, drupal, rest, rpc

Добрый день.

Сейчас разбираюсь с модулем services и хочу задать несколько вопросов.

Каким образом узнать, какие параметры передавать методам сервиса? Например, я хочу залогиниться с помощью метода "user.login" или удалить ноду с помощью "node.delete". А с какими параметрами эти методы вызывать - могу только догадываться.

В Firefox с помощью расширения XML-RPC Client пытаюсь произвести операции с методами. И часто возникает ошибка "CSRF validation failed". А каком случае она будет возникать и как эту проблему решать ?

Зарегистировал на сайте сервис, работающий через REST. Но при попытке обратиться с помощью приложения postman возвращается Access Forbidden.
В частности, сервис имеет путь test и выполняет такой вот запрос - http://dexam/test/node.

Есть ли нормальная документация, статьи или видеоуроки по данной теме ? А то документация, на которую идут ссылки на странице модуля, какая-то слабоватая.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет модуль services_definition, теперь он часть https://www.drupal.org/project/services_tools. Появится вкладка Definition, где будут перечислены все url и параметры для них.

А также замечательный курс https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-building-services-drupal-7-series?p=1487

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже разобрался